# FFmpeg concat filter

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, concatenation, video-processing

I have 2 same videos. One of the videos doesn't have audio and I want to `concat` them.

```
video1 = 1 video stream + 1 audio stream.
video2 = 1 video stream.
the result should be 1(concatenated) video stream, 1 audio stream
```

I have tried

```
ffmpeg -i videoonly.mov -i video+audio.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mov
```

but it doesn't work and prints the error message

```
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v][0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.
```

I except this kind of error message because the second video doesn't have the audio and I sepcifyed the audio but the question is how to make it work or is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concat filter expects matching pairs in each segment, so if one of the segment does not have audio, you should supply a dummy stream. Below, I use the anullsrc filter to generate one.

```
ffmpeg -i videoonly.mov -i video+audio.mov -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v][2:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mov
```

Comment: One more question.
As you marked in your answer `filter expects matching pairs in each segment` how to contact 2 files with the following case.
`File1` 0 video track, 1 audio track.
`File2` 1 video track, 1 audio track.
Does this mean that I have to generate a `video track` for contacting it?.
If yes then how?.
Thanks in advance.